# Weird output length using for

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to have a test to see if my data makes sense, so I want to compare 2 columns of my dataset. It has to do with distances, so I compare Yn - Yn-1 to Xn - Xn-1.

```
x<-c(1,2,3,0,2,0,5,8,2,10,2,0,1,0)
CSx<-cumsum(x)
y<-c(1,1.5,2,2,3,3,2,6,1,8,9,10,11,12)
test1<-as.data.frame(cbind(x, CSx, y))
bla<-NA
for (n in 2:length(test1[,1])){
 j<-test1[n,2]
 k<-test1[n-1,2]
 l<-test1[n,3]
 m<-test1[n-1,3]
 ifelse((l-m)/(j-k)>1, bla<-append(bla, "WRONG!!!"), bla<-append(bla, "ok"))
}
```

I therefore expect to have `length(test1)` values, the first being `NA`, and then 13 calculated values, from 2 to 14 in these case. I only get 12:

```
> length(2:length(test1[,1]))
# [1] 13
> bla
# [1] NA         "ok"       "ok"       "ok"       "ok"       "ok"      
# [7] "ok"       "ok"       "ok"       "WRONG!!!" "ok"       "WRONG!!!"
> length(bla)
# [1] 12
```

I guess there is a perfectly logical and simple reason for this, but I am utterly confused.

Comment: a short alternative: `a = diff(CSx); b= diff(y); b>a`. `diff` calculates the difference between value n and value n-1. There is no division in this, so the error message won't appear.

Answer (score 1):

If you put this command `cat(n,"  ",(l-m)/(j-k),"\n")` in your for loop, you'll see that for `n` equal to 4 and 6 `(l-m)/(j-k)` is equal to `NA` because `0/0` is `NaN` in R. Therefore the function `ifelse` does not work. You have to handle NA values.

For example:

```
x<-c(1,2,3,0,2,0,5,8,2,10,2,0,1,0)
CSx<-cumsum(x)
y<-c(1,1.5,2,2,3,3,2,6,1,8,9,10,11,12)
test1<-as.data.frame(cbind(x, CSx, y))
bla<-NA

for (n in 2:length(test1[,1])){
    j<-test1[n,2]
    k<-test1[n-1,2]
    l<-test1[n,3]
    m<-test1[n-1,3]

    if (is.na((l-m)/(j-k)))
      bla <- append(bla, "whatever you want")

    ifelse((l-m)/(j-k)>1, bla<-append(bla, "WRONG!!!"), bla<-append(bla, "ok"))

}
```

Comment: Ok, it makes sense indeed! Thanks a lot!